# CakePhp join models together

Tags: cakephp, recursion, relationship

`Cakephp 2.7` with `mssql` database

I have 2 main tables in database and their relation is belongs-to.
Recursion for index action is set to 1, on both tables.

`table2` belongs to `table1`.

I need to load `table1` with their belongs-to relation and i need also `table2` belongs-to relation on index of `table1`, but only to recursion value 1.

If i set `recursion` to 2, then it goes too deep.

I tried has-one, belongs-to, recursion012.

resolved..
i added another find method in index. and set/send that var to index.ctp.
tnx

Comment: Can you post the `find` operation you've already tried and basic model information so we have a better shot at answering your question?

Comment: The answer is not to add another `find()`. The answer to use 'Containable'. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Containable** behavior instead of **recursive** option to get data from desired table. For more info see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some code showing an example.